# HTML reference to image file on Google Drive does not work

Tags: html

I want to embed an icon for my website. The relevant HTML shall retrieve it via "src=..." from a folder on my Google Drive. I have given the folder and also the image file public access rights. (Finally I want the HTML code to run on the Google platform as well but I can demonstrate the issue also with a locally stored HTML file.)

When I use the links to my folder or to the image file directly in my browser, they show up. I therefore think that there is no authority issue. Also when I use a reference to a copy of the image file on my local PC, it works.

The code below shows 4 cases. The first 2, referring to the locally stored file, work and the last 2, referring to the file on the Google drive, do not work.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    Test on local PC
    <br><br>
    </head>
    <body>

    1. Image from same directory in which this html code resides
    <br>
    Method: src="test.png"
    <br>
    <img id="myImg" src="test.png" width="50" height="50">
    <br>

    2. Image from directory on local PC
    <br>
    Method: src="C:/Users/MattheisenP/Desktop/test.png"
    <br>
    <img id="myImg" src="C:/Users/MattheisenP/Desktop/test.png" width="50" height="50">
    <br>

    3. Image from directory on Google Drive using the drive's key
    <br>
    Method: src="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B9P-4EpF1HhMXzdoQ2tJSXotVmc/test.png"
    <br>
    Using this url... https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B9P-4EpF1HhMXzdoQ2tJSXotVmc  in the browser brings me to the folder
    <br>
    <img id="myImg" src="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B9P-4EpF1HhMXzdoQ2tJSXotVmc/test.png" width="50" height="50">
    <br>


    4. Image from directory on Google Drive using the files key
    <br>
    Method: src= "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P-4EpF1HhMb0trR1NXbVhXNTg"
    <br>
    Using this url... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P-4EpF1HhMb0trR1NXbVhXNTg  in the browser displays the icon
    <br>
    <img id="myImg" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P-4EpF1HhMb0trR1NXbVhXNTg" width="50" height="50">
    <br>
    </body>
```

The outcome is as follows:
[image]

As you see, the last two fail. What is wrong with my syntax or my understanding of the concept?

Thanks for any helpful hint.

Answer (score 1):

Now I found a syntax which works:
https://docs.google.com/uc?id= enhanced with the FileID. In the example above the statement

```
        <img id="myImg" src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B9P-4EpF1HhMb0trR1NXbVhXNTg" width="50" height="50">
```

gives the expected result and the icon is shown. So, the file ID was correct as well as the access rights. But the methods/syntax as proposed in several articles and used in case 3 and 4 above did not work (at least not for me). The syntax with https://docs.google.com/uc?id= provides the image as required.

Comment: this worked for me too, it seems Google changes the public prefix from time to time